# Assembly.LoadFrom dependency search order

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies

I want to know in what order and in whcih directories LoadFrom searches for dependencies of loading assembly. I know, that It searches in GAC, program folder and some of other directories but I don't know neither order, nor exact pathes for searching.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Order of Assemblies Being Loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954257/the-order-of-assemblies-being-loaded)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First it will search in BIN, then it will search in GAC.